# Yii URL Manager: problems in create an view url

Tags: yii, url-rewriting

in file config main.php:

```
'/view-details/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9]+>' => array('product/details', 'urlSuffix' => '.html')
```

create url:

```
$this->createUrl('product/details', array('slug'=>'my-product-demo-with-id-123'));
```

result:

`mydomain/view-details/my-product-demo-with-id-123.html`

(done! perfect generate url)

but, when visit link, this is error: unsolved request view-details/my-product-demo-with-id-123.html

if remove all character "-" (mydomain/view-details/MyProductDemoWithID123.html), it's working, not error.

what is problems? somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you're using will only match single words but your url has hyphens as well.

You need to have a rule that looks like this

```
'/view-details/<slug:[-\w]+>' => array('product/details', 'urlSuffix' => '.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (new at Yii!) but probably this can be related to a bad method in your Controller actionView().
Look if you have in your controller "View-details" a method similiar to "actionMyProductDemoWithID123()" and inside of this, you render that file.

Example: yourDomain/yourController/yourView

```
Class YourController{
      actionYourView(){
        $this->render('yourView');
   }
}
```

In your case, you probably have something similar to this:

```
Class view-details{
          actionMyProductDemoWithId123(){
            $this->render('MyProductDemoWithID123');
       }
    }
```

If it's not, you can take a look at this post: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/404/hyphenation-of-routes-in-url-management/

Answer (score 0):

You missed the "-" part of your regex so it won't match try

```
'/view-details/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+>' => array('product/details', 'urlSuffix' => '.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you are allowing only alphanumeric values. Your have to allow "-" also as you are using in your parameter(slug).

Regex with Alphanumeric and -,_

```
'view-details/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+>' => array('product/details','urlSuffix' => '.html'),
```